# Make pairs of file and columns for use in a loop?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to make a pair of file and the columns that will be needed from it in a loop.

I am thinking a dictionary would be ok but not sure.

Example:

```
files: file1,file2,file3,etc

dict1 = ({file1:its needed columns,file2:its needed columns})
```

Later it will be used in this function:

```
for i in dict1: # below it reads the files from arcpy - not important 
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=arcpy.da.SearchCursor("key_of_dict",
                                                     ['the_one_column','the_other_column'])

    #then make a new column that will apply the value_counts to a certain column
    df['count_of_a_col']=[df['one_col'].value_counts().loc[x] for x in df['one_col']]
```

How can I make this work?

**Note**

The columns will not always be the same in each file.
For one file we need two certain columns and for another totally different. That's why I think about using dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
dict1 = {'file_name_1': ['on_column', 'another_column'], 'file_name_2': ['again_column']}
for k, v in dict1.items():
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=arcpy.da.SearchCursor(k, v))
    column_for_count = v[1] if len(v) >= 2 else v[0]
    df['count_of_' + column_for_count]=[df[column_for_count].value_counts().loc[x] for x in df[column_for_count]]
    # do what you want with v
```

Comment: Upvoted! this is based on the idea in the question.Do you think a different approach may be better?

Comment: I don't think so. Simple better than complex

Comment: The problem with this is that since there are different columns how the last line of code in my question will work in the loop?

Comment: i mean the names of the columns will be different in each loop how to solve this problem

Comment: But you wont to have one name of the column in each step? Am I right?

Comment: But if in other occasions there are values in  the dict for columns i will be using index: `v[1]` and if there is one column as value in the dict the v[1] will give error.

Comment: @ AndMar Can you help on this?

Comment: What do you want to get if list is empty or has 1 element inside? Just skip this iteration?

Comment: if only 1 element inside I want to have that element. therefore v[1] will throw error because only one element would be there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183007/discussion-between-andmar-and-user51332).